# What does adding "new" do to make this program work?

Tags: java, swing

What does the "new ga();" mean and why wouldn't this program work if it was just "ga();". I'm still trying to wrap my head around all the programming terms/language.

```java
public class ga extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ga();
    }

    public ga() {
        setSize(500, 400);
        setTitle("test");
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be using Swing. Are you using Swing?

Comment: the "method" `ga` is a constructor of the class `ga`. Calling a construtor can only be done while creating a new instance of a class, which you do using the `new` keyword.

Comment: @Sweeper why is that relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Your ga() "method" is actually the constructor of your class.
The syntax of a constructor is:

```
public [Classname](parameters...){     //you can view it as a nameless method with the
                                       //return type of your class
   ...
}
```

You call the constructor, when you want to create a new Object of that class, as in your code, or like this, if you want to keep a reference on the new Object:

```
Ga myGaObject1 = new Ga();
```

**IMPORTANT:** in Java, you normally start classnames with a capital letter, so "Ga", not "ga" (same for the Constructor).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call `ga()` ,you need to make

```
public ga() {
...
}
```

,a constructor, to a method.
Because `ga()` is not a method , compile finds that syntax error and show you a cross.

`new` is a Java keyword. It creates a Java object and allocates memory for it on the heap.[what's new?](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/new)

Usually, we declare Variable Type first and assign value to it.

```
Ga myObject ;
```

Then assign value to it.

```
myObject = new Ga();
```

Assignment in Java is the process of giving a value to a primitive-type variable or giving an object **reference** to an object-type variable. [what is Assignment '='?](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/what-is-an-assignment-statement-in-java)